# SSRS report deployment on azure

Tags: azure

I am using SSRS report in my web application now, I want to deploy SSRS report on azure, I found one option using azure VM but its costly as I am using free account, Is there any other option?
Please suggest me the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Now spinning a SQL Server VM might result in costs way higher than you might expect (due to licenses), so always make sure you run it on a version of SQL Server Developer, which has all the features of the highest SQL edition, but it is free (not to be run in production). See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-sql-server-2016-developer-image-in-the-azure-gallery/).

If you use one of the SQL Gallery Images, then you don't need an additional SQL Server license. See Azure VM pricing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/)

You can try [Pay-As-You-Go option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-upgrade-azure-subscription) 
You need to be more specific - the cost of licensing what? Azure SQL Reporting? Virtual Machines? SQL Server licensing?
you would have to set up SSRS somewhere. Azure-hosted VM depends on a lot of factors such as your budget, on-premise infrastructure capacity, overall cloud strategy of your organization.

Licensing - Azure lets you pay directly for VMs that include SSRS. For example you can get SQL Server Standard 2012 (which includes SSRS) on a "Small" Server 2012 vm for about